# jQuery on page load, perform like a click function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a click function which runs code similar to the following:

```
$('#go').click(function(e){
    var url = $("#url").val();
    $this = $("#convert");
    $this.css({"text-align":"center","font-size":"18px"});
    $this.html("<a href='http://www.site.com/out/?u=" + url + "'>You will be redirected in <span id='counter'></span> seconds!</a>")
    var count = 10;
    var counter = document.getElementById('counter');

    setInterval(function(){
       count--;
       counter.innerHTML = count;

       if (count === 0) {
          window.location = 'http://www.site.com/out/?u=' + url;
       }
    }, 1000);
});
```

but I also want this to be triggered on page load.. for example, if the visitor goes to a url like:

> http://www.site.com/#http://www.google.com

It'll run the click function on the URL after the hash sort of thing..

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Name the function and use it twice, as a `click` handler, and a `hashchange` handler. I don't really understand the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jquery on load fire click event:

```
    $(function(){
        $('#go').click();
    })
```